# jQtouch CSS Header Bar

Tags: css, header

I'm using jQtouch for a small mobile app.  Using the [default CSS](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/source/browse/trunk/themes/jqt/theme.css) the app looks like I want it to.  However, I need to have a header on the left and right of the page. For example,
[alt text http://shaiperednik.com/img/AV-Clock-20091028-084713.png](http://shaiperednik.com/img/AV-Clock-20091028-084713.png)

If anyone can point me in the right direction to achieve this I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: my temporary solution was to use tables, but I think there should be a proper css way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about some standard css? Something like this:

```
div.leftHeader
{
    float: left;
}
div.rightHeader
{
    float: right;
}
div.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

And then use this HTML code:

```
<div class="leftHeader">In</div>
<div class="rightHeader">Day/Week</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: I have to mark this one as right because it works and its using CSS.  Tables are evil http://goo.gl/TLm6

Comment: Using `<table>` for layout is bad, but using it to display tabular data is semantically correct.  And CSS is used to style `<table>` as well.

Answer (score 2):

shaiss,

I think using `<table>` selectors is the way to go.

In my opinion, your app is displaying tabular data.  Therefore, I think **"In"** and **"Day/Week"** should be column headers.  Use `<th></th>` instead of a `<td></td>` to define header cells.  You need to wrap `<th>` in `<tr></tr>` and `<thead>` and `<tbody>` are optional:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can position the `<th>` with the **"In"** like so:

```
thead th.left
{
  text-align: left;
}​
```

Full source code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/g3MKj/

Of course, something like Jan Aagaard's code could work for you.  But just for the sake of learning, another way to accomplish the same thing in CSS is:

```
span.absolute-right
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span>In</span>
<span class="absolute-right">Day/Week</span>
```

I have this example, and Jan Aagaard's, plus another example using `position:relative` here: http://jsfiddle.net/L7fTp/